# Output pdf is not getting generated in case of internationization

Tags: pdftex, russian, english

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1, T2A]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{abstract}
Это вводный абзац в начале документа.
\end{abstract}
 Этот текст будет на русском языке. Это демонстрация того, что символы кириллицы
 в сгенерированном документе (Compile to PDF) отображаются правильно.
 Для этого Вы должны установить нужный  язык (russian) 
и необходимую кодировку шрифта (T2A).

\selectlanguage{english}
This text will be in English. The elements within this 
block of text will also be set in the right language.

\begin{abstract}
A brief description of the main subject to be 
explained in the entire document.
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{russian}
Кириллические символы также могут быть использованы в математическом режиме.

\begin{equation}
  S_\textup{ис} = S_{123}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I am using above code to generate the document using miktex -> pdf latex.
but document is not getting generated.

This is what I am getting in log file.
https://pastebin.com/cgU2pYLG

And this is what I am getting at console

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.1029]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator>C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\LatexToPDF.bat

C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator>CD C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\miktex\bin

C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\miktex\bin>pdflatex --output-directory="C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator" --file-line-error --interaction=nonstopmode "C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\report.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(C:/Users/kesarkas/AppData/Local/Temp/ReportGenerator/report.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2009-06-19, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, lao, latin, lat
vian, lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerm
an, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese,
romanian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swis
sgerman, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, u
senglishmax, welsh, loaded.
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\latex\base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\latex\base\size10.clo))
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\latex\base\inputenc.sty
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\utf8.def
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\t1enc.dfu)
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\ot1enc.dfu)
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\omsenc.dfu)))
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\generic\babel\babel.sty
*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\latex\00miktex\bblopts.cfg)
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\generic\babel\english.ldf
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\generic\babel\babel.def))
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\russianb.ldf

Package babel Warning: No Cyrillic font encoding has been loaded so far.
(babel)                A font encoding should be declared before babel.
(babel)                Default `T2A' encoding will be loaded  on input line 74.


(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\t2aenc.def
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\t2aenc.dfu))))
(C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\t1enc.def)
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\t2aenc.def)
(C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\t2acmr.fd)pdflatex: The font creation utility could not be found.
pdflatex: Data: miktex-maketfm.exe

C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\miktex\bin>
```

Comment: The `.log` file probably got truncated due to length limits. Maybe you can post it elsewhere (https://pastebin.com/ or GitHub gists) and/or repost it here, but remove all the `defining Unicode char ...` lines to make it more compact.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cgU2pYLG

Please check above link for log file

and I see only this much in log file so not able to figure out what is the issue exactly.

Comment: What exactly happens when you compile your document? Do you get any error in the console output? Does compiliation even ever finish?

Comment: Your document is missing the `\end{document}`. If I add that it compiles just fine for me. The `.log` file does not contain any obvious warnings or errors. But it shows that your system is seriously outdated (last update around 2011).

Comment: @moewe actually I forgot to paste it in question. but at my place I am having \end{document} at the end.

Comment: @siracusa please check updated question, for console output

Comment: So `miktex-maketfm.exe` seems to be missing. As this tool should be part of the MiKTeX core installation, I suspect your MiKTeX installation being broken/incomplete. You can check for updates of the `miktex-*` packages from [the MiKTeX console](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console).

Comment: You seem to call pdflatex from the bin folder, which probably means that your PATH variable is not correctly set.

Answer (score 1):

Your method to call pdflatex is wrong. (I split it for the remarks):

```
C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\miktex\bin>pdflatex
```

You should not start pdflatex in the bin folder. Correct would be to switch to the folder of the document and call pdflatex from there

```
C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator> pdflatex
```

```
  --output-directory="C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator"
```

You are trying to output the files to folder of your document, which is unnecessary if you call pdflatex correctly.

```
 "C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator\report.tex"
```

You should never pass an absolute path to pdflatex correct would be simply

```
 report
```

So the correct call is

```
 C:\Users\kesarkas\AppData\Local\Temp\ReportGenerator> pdflatex --file-line-error --interaction=nonstopmode report
```

If this reports that pdflatex is not found, you should add

```
  C:\KBData\NGworkspace\Branch\Out\Print\PDF\miktex\bin
```

to your windows PATH variable.